# Cannot kill emacs with M-x kill-emacs

Tags: emacs

I am trying to quit emacs with `M-x kill-emacs` but I get this message: `Buffer cache/ido.last modified; kill anyway (y or n)`. When I choose `y` I get `/Users/a/.emacs.d/cache/: no such directory`.

This is stopping me from `M-x eval-buffer` to install packages with marmalade. How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

I created a `/cache/` directory in `/.emacs.d` and changed its permissions to `777` and I was able to kill emacs. Can you take a look at these permissions and let me know if I need to make changes?

```
as-MacBook-Air:.emacs.d a$ ls -la
total 24
drwx------  11 a  staff   374 Dec 18 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 34 a  staff  1156 Dec 18 12:20 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 a  staff   195 Dec 18 12:20 .smex-items
drwx------   3 a  staff   102 Dec 12 21:04 auto-save-list
drwxr-xr-x  21 a  staff   714 Dec 18 12:20 backups
drwxrwxrwx   2 a  admin    68 Dec 18 12:08 cache
drwxr-xr-x  23 a  staff   782 Dec 18 08:51 elpa
drwx------   4 a  staff   136 Dec 18 08:23 eshell
-rw-r--r--   1 a  staff   195 Dec 18 12:20 places
-rw-r--r--   1 a  staff  1505 Dec 18 12:20 tramp
drwxr-xr-x   4 a  staff   136 Dec 18 09:19 url
```

Comment: Create the directory manually.  You can also look for the variable where that directory is set (e.g., `ido-save-directory-list-file`) and change the location if you so prefer.  Or disable the ido save.

Comment: Here is an example of how to change the location:  `(setq ido-save-directory-list-file "~/.emacs.d/ido.last")`

Comment: I commented out `;; ido-save-directory-list-file "~/.emacs.d/ido.last"` but I still get the same "no such directory" error and emacs does not quit. In your second comment, do I paste (setq ido-save-directory-list-file "~/.emacs.d/ido.last") in .emacs?

Comment: I also found this answer which may relate to my case (because I was having problems editing files because they were owned by root). I tried the `C-z` as suggested when I got the `Buffer cache/ido.last modified; kill anyway (y or n) prompt` but "C-z" does not nothing for me. When do I enter "C-z"? Thanks.

Comment: You need to choose a directory that exists -- just because the directory `~/.emacs.d/` exists on my computer, doesn't mean that it exists on your computer.  Choose your own directory that you are certain exists -- and of course you will need permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: I am sorry, in .emacs I changed `ido-save-directory-list-file "~/ido.last"` so "cache" is not there but when I try to kill I still get the same message. emacs tries to save to /cache/. Then, do I need to create /cache/. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks, please see my edits to the question. I created the /cache directory and changed its permissions and it worked.

Comment: You made a good choice. I spent a few minutes searching `ido.el` before I posted my comments, but was unable to readily locate the code where the directory `cache` is specified.  If you are interested and have some free time, that would be the place to look to make further configurations of the `cache` directory.  There may be other files that will be stored in that directory, so care would be needed when modifying that location if you so choose.  There are a lot of words `cache` inside `ido.el` , so searching may take time if you're interested.  Since it's working now, you can call it a wrap.

Comment: @lawlist: do you think you can add an answer so that I can select it?

Comment: Before writing an answer, I'd like to have a better understanding of where the `cache` directory is set within `ido.el` -- probably concatenated (appended to the ending) of the `user-emacs-directory`.  I'll place it on my todo list . . .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to workaround the issue of ido preventing emacs from exiting when the 'ido.last' file is not writable:

```
(defun ido-kill-emacs-hook () (ignore-errors (ido-save-history)))
```